# php codeigniter upload file error

Tags: php, codeigniter

this is my controller function and below is my view file code pleas help to find out the error in my code

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Upload extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }


    function test(){
        if($this->input->post('submit')){
            $config['upload_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/assets/uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'mp4';
             $this->load->library('upload',$config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload()){
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            }else{
                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            }
        }   
        $this->load->view('upload/test');
    }

}
?>
```

and this is my view code->

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    Select File To Upload:<br />
    <input type="file" name="userfile"  />
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-success" />
</form>
```

and i  m getting errors are ->
[image]

Comment: its clearly says that it not able to load the upload library. You need to check that your upload library is available to load in controller or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got this working,it took whole day. I was developing this on **CI version->3.0** and when i **replace my system folder** with the new updated **CI VERSION->3.0rc2** it worked like a charm in a single go and didn't change a single line in the above code.Both are development version of CI-3.But in the updated version my form validation stopped working, but as in the last version it was working fine so i copied my old version **system/library/form_validation.php** to new version at the same place and it is working fine now.